# Hyper-V Server 2016 and File Share

Tags: windows, hyper-v, file-sharing

company's corporative rules prohibit us to implement something new without successfully passing all the tests in the test lab. Right now we have two nodes with Hyper-V Server 2016 on top. The only useful link I found regarding this situation https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/free-smb3-failover-file-server-on-microsoft-hyper-v-server-2016  So I wonder, is there any other possibility to create something similar to file share with Microsoft free version and what do you think about such implementation, should I try to use it?

Comment: Legally you can't do that: free Hyper-V Server is for virtualization purpose only, you can run VMs but you can't expose file services, run non-virtualized AD controllers there etc. If you want to use free Hyper-V Server as your corporate SMB3 file server you have to buy CALs.

Comment: ...and you can go server-less pushing your file services workload to public cloud. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely, you can deploy File Server on a free Windows Server version. Moreover, you can create high available Failover File Server over your Hyper-V Server. The only concern here is license question. If you make it, you will violate the Microsoft license agreement so make at your own risk.